# Create azure storage container through powershell in new portal

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-storage

I want to create an azure storage container in an existing storage account, through powershell.I have tried the following commands:

```
Set-AzureSubscription -CurrentStorageAccountName "storageaccountv1" -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionId
New-AzureStorageContainer -Name $ContainerName -Permission Off
```

For those who know, Azure has two types of storage accounts: v1, v2. v1 accounts are the ones that are available through the http://manage.windowsazure.com/ and v2 that can be created in http://portal.azure.com/. While the command New-AzureStorageContainer is working with a storage account in v1, the command is not working for a storage account in v2. It is giving the following error:

```
New-AzureStorageContainer : ResourceNotFound: The storage account 'storageaccountv2' was not found.
At CreateStorageContainer.ps1:31 char:1
+ New-AzureStorageContainer -Name $ContainerName -Permission Off
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureStorageContainer], CloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CloudException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Blob.Cmdlet.NewAzureStorageContainerCommand
```

Can anyone tell how to create an azure storage container in v2 through powershell?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If using `StorageAccountContext` is an option, you can try the following:

```
$ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName "account-name" -StorageAccountKey "account-key" 
New-AzureStorageContainer -Name "container-name" -Context $ctx
```

Comment: This is helping. But wish there might be a way to do this without specifying the storage account key.

Answer (score 4):

Azure PowerShell 1.0 Preview （https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azps-1-0-pre/） is release.

With Azure PowerShell 1.0 Preview, you can run following cmdlets:

```
 Login-AzureRMAccount -SubscriptionId [SubscriptionID]
 Set-AzureRmCurrentStorageAccount -StorageAccountName [accountName] -ResourceGroupName [ResourceGroupName]
```

Then you can run "New-AzureStorageContainer" with resource mode account (create in new portal) without context.

BTW, "Set-AzureSubscription" is only for Service mode account, not applicable to resource mode account.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the idempotent code

```
[System.String]$script:ResourceGroupNameVariable = 'resourcegroupnameone'
[System.String]$script:StorageAccountNameVariable = 'storacctnameone'
[System.String]$script:ContainerNameVariable = 'containernameone'

Write-Host "Start Container Create"

#Get/Set the AzureRmStorageAccountKey
#                        the below -Name parameter may be -AccountName according to documentation
[System.Object[]]$currentAzureRmStorageAccountKeys = Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $script:ResourceGroupNameVariable -Name $script:StorageAccountNameVariable;
#Write-Host "about to currentAzureRmStorageAccountKeys.GetType"
#Write-Output $currentAzureRmStorageAccountKeys.GetType().FullName 


### Create the AzureStorageContext (you always do this, regardless if the container itself exists or not)
[Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.AzureStorageContext]$currentAzureStorageContext = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $script:StorageAccountNameVariable -StorageAccountKey $currentAzureRmStorageAccountKeys[0].Value;
#Write-Host "about to currentAzureStorageContext.GetType"
#Write-Output $currentAzureStorageContext.GetType().FullName 

# Get/Set the AzureStorageContainer
[Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageContainer]$currentAzureStorageContainerCheck=Get-AzureStorageContainer -Context $currentAzureStorageContext -Name $script:ContainerNameVariable;

if(!$currentAzureStorageContainerCheck)
{
    ### The container does not already exist.  Create a Blob Container in the Storage Account
    New-AzureStorageContainer -Context $currentAzureStorageContext -Name $script:ContainerNameVariable;
}
else{
    #Write-Host "about to currentAzureStorageContainerCheck.GetType"
    #Write-Output $currentAzureStorageContainerCheck.GetType().FullName 
    #Write-Host "about to currentAzureStorageContainerCheck"
    #$currentAzureStorageContainerCheck
}

Write-Host "End Container Create"
```

This runs against : Version      4.3.1  (of     AzureRM )

> get-module –listavailable -Name "AzureRM"

Answer (score 0):

this helped but I needed the ARM command and not the classic method. 
Hope it helps

`$NewRGName = 'Lab'`
`$NewRGLocation = "West US"`
`$NewStrAccName ="Labstorage2"`
`$SkuName = 'Standard_LRS'`
 `# Create new storage account`
`New-AzureRmStorageAccount -Location $NewRGLocation -Name $NewStrAccName -ResourceGroupName $NewRGName -SkuName $SkuName`